Swiper slidechange event sometimes called a second time resetting back to the initial slide
I am using Swiper 11.1.9 in my Angular 18.1.1 application.
I have a simple 2 slides going from one view to another. I have hooked up to the slidechange so I can save the last slide used.
Normally this all works fine, but I find, if while in a slide, if I reload my data via an HTTPS call, which resets the data in a chartjs chart I have, if I then go to slide to the other slide, I first have the correct slidechange with the new index set, but then it seems to set itself back to the slide I just came from.
My handler looks like this where I log out each time the index changes:
public async slideChanged(ev: any): Promise<void> {
try {
  this.loggerBase.info('Performance getting active index...');
  const swiper: Swiper = ev.detail[0];

  this.currentSliderIndex = swiper.activeIndex;
  if (!this.currentSliderIndex) {
    this.currentSliderIndex = 0;
  }

  this.errors = '';
  this.loggerBase.info(`Performance index set to ${this.currentSliderIndex}`);
  this.dataStore.setNumber(DataStorageKeys.vals.performancePageLastActiveSlideIndex, this.currentSliderIndex);
  await this.setupCurrentSliderPage();
  this.subscribeToUpdates();
} catch (error) {
  this.loggerBase.error(`performance.slideChanged: ${error}`);
}

When it goes wrong, I slide to index no 1, and I see the above handler being called with slide index of 1 (correct), but it is then called a second time with the index set back to 0! So the swiper flicks to the new slide, but then goes back to where we came from.
In the call stack we can see the two simultaneous calls:

Also, when it is going back to slide 0, it has slide direct of next:

Whereas normally, when going back to index 0 this would be prev.
I set the loop property to false, but this made no difference.
 <swiper-container events-prefix="swiper-" [modules]="swiperModules" [loop]="false" [pagination]="true" #swiper (swiper-slidechange)='slideChanged($event)'>

What is causing this, and how can I prevent this?
Update 1
So far I cannot repo in a sample app. I created a new Ionic/Angular application and tried to get the layout similar to my real app. but cannot reproduce.
I did find in my app, it is as soon as open any "modal", even an alert via a button click that I soon start having this issue.
For example, in one of the components that sits inside a swiper-slide I add...
<ion-button (click)="testButton()">This is a test button</ion-button>
....

testButton(): void {
   alert('testButton');   
}

Opening this one or two times, I start getting the issue. I had removed the chart element and this still made no difference. Of course I can't rebuild my whole app in a sample, so it is very hard to know what the "magic" breaking bit is.
Update 2 - Reproduce
I have finally reproduced in the example here here
The issue was cause by me calling the Ionic `LoadingController1 spinner and then removing it.
I.e. From the slideChanged handler I call the presentDataLoading while loading data and then dismissLoaderIfPresent.
However this only happens if you first open one of the selects, and then slide to the next page.
So not sure if this is the Ionic issue or Swiper, and not sure why they conflict (I use the Ionic spinner everywhere).

please share the minimal reproducible code, if possible a stackblitz with the issue replicated.

@NarenMurali - I have reproduced in a sample app. Put the details and link in the main post as "UPDATE 2 - Preproduce"
